# Show media preview in QML / QtQuick2

Tags: video, qml, qt5, preview

I am successfully playing video from QML using `MediaPlayer` and `VideoOutput` elements, however is there any native/simple/recommended practice of generating preview icons for media source such as video files and/or streams?

Example: In my application I have a list of files that I show to the user in a list. When the user clicks an item it will start playing. To aid the user in selecting the desired item, I would like to decorate each item with a small image icon that shows a frame of the video for that item. If the item does not contain video, it will simply show a generic picture icon instead.

How would I go about this?

Comment: Did you solve the mentioned problem?

Comment: I can't recall that I did. I think you will have to generate the previews in code which might be non-trivial. Basically start video, pause, seek to start, make and cache a thumbnail.